# Airflow task improperly has an `upstream_failed` status after previous task succeeded after 1 retry

Tags: airflow, mwaa

[image]

I have two tasks A and B. Task A failed once but the retry succeeded and is marked as a success (green). I would expect Task B to perform normally since Task A retry succeeded but it is marked as **upstream_failed** and was not triggered. Is this a way to fix this behavior?

The Task B has an **ALL_SUCCESS** trigger rule.

I am using Airflow 2.0.2 on AWS (MWAA).

Comment: Post the dag code please

Comment: there is similar behavior reported here https://github.com/apache/airflow/discussions/33528 for MWAA Airflow version 2.2.2 . They suggest it is MWAA specific issue, as i understand. Also, I have same issue with MWAA and Airflow 2.6.3 .

Answer (score 1):

**Trying to restart the scheduler.**

###### `upstream_failed` happened from scheduler flow or when depends are seting to `failed` state, you can check states from [Task Instances](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/tasks.html#task-instances)

[image: Task Instances from Airflow Docs]

#### in Retry Mode:

- Task A will be in `up_for_retry` state until exceed `retries` number.
- If `trigger_rule` set with `all_success`(it's default [trigger rule](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.3/concepts.html?highlight=trigger%20rule#trigger-rules)), Task B will not trigger untill Task A finished, If every thing running correctly.

##### Could you add the DAG implementation?

Answer (score 0):

It is caused by MWAA auto-scale feature. When it scales down after going up, the allocated workers per scheduled task is killed, and the task may end up in such state.
What helped me is to increase min number of workers (! default is 1, and increasing it would result in additional costs, of course). Analyze your environment usage in cost explorer to see how often and how much it scales up by checking # of hours. Then increase min number of workers accordingly. In my case, increasing the value to 3 helped to mitigate the issue.
It is even mentioned in the official documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/mwaa-autoscaling.html#mwaa-autoscaling-stranded, right in the note, quote:

> When downscaling occurs, it is possible for new tasks to be scheduled.
> Furthermore, it's possible for workers that are set for deletion to
> pick up those tasks before the worker containers are removed. This
> period can last between two to five minutes, due to a combination of
> factors: the time it takes for the Apache Airflow metrics to be sent,
> the time to detect a steady state of zero tasks, and the time it takes
> the Fargate workers to be removed.
>
> If you use Amazon MWAA with periods of sustained workload, followed by
> periods of no workload, you will be unaffected by this limitation.
> However, if you have very intermittent workloads with repeated high
> usage, followed by zero tasks for approximately five minutes, you
> might be affected by this issue when tasks running on the downscaled
> workers are deleted and marked as failed